# Is there a Java equivalent of the C# XmlWriter?

Tags: java, xml, xmlwriter

I am looking for a simple lightweight way to write an XML file using Java. One that does **not** first build the output up in memory because some of the XML files we create are very large.

.NET has this with [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx). Does Java have this anywhere?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the native [XMLStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) or reference to this extended [XMLWriter](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/XMLWriterjavaserializeanXMLdocument.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The closest equivalent would be the [XMLStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) class in the StAX API.

Comment: A lot of people still imagine that StAX is all about pull parsing, whereas in fact its XML-writing interface is probably the most useful thing it offers.